# Recursion or extracting a variable

Tags: c, recursion

```
void base_aux(unsigned int n, unsigned int base, unsigned int x) {
    zero_int(32 - x);
    if (n > (base - 1)) {
        base_aux(n / base, base, ++x);
        printf("%u", n % base);
    } else {
        printf("%u", n);
    } 
}

void binary_int(unsigned int n) {
    base_aux(n, 2, 0);
}
```

I'm making a converter from decimal to whatever base. I have to use recursion and need to print leading zeros. I would like for the zeros to print without it recursing. I would just call it in my actual function, but then I don't know how to get the incremented x from this. Please help.

zero_int is a helper function which will simply print as many zeroes as are needed.

i.e 
what I get at the moment when I attempt to convert 1288 to decimal is  000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010100001000.

What I would like to get is 00000000000000000000010100001000.

I see that this is because with each recursive call it repeatedly places those leading zeroes, which creates too many, but I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: What? Give an example of what you get, why it is not good enough and what would you want.

Comment: I've updated the question to provide those clarifications

Comment: Supposing the base is 3, 4, 7, 8 or 36 — why would you need 32-x zeroes in each of those cases?  If you only work with base 2 (binary), then there might be some justice in using some such calculation, though I remain to be convinced you've got it correct (and so do you since you wouldn't be asking the question if everything was working).

Comment: It's part of the instruction. I need to ensure that 32 bits are being represented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering only for base 2 (binary):

The trouble lies in the place where you are calling zero_int function. You need to ensure it is called only once and with the correct value of x.

Modifying your code like below should mostly work:

```
void base_aux(unsigned int n, unsigned int base, unsigned int x) {
    if (n > (base - 1)) {
        base_aux(n / base, base, ++x);
        printf("%u", n % base);
    } else {
        ++x;
        zero_int(32 - x);
        printf("%u", n);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add an extra if check "32 - x > 0"

```
#include "stdio.h"

void base_aux(unsigned int n, unsigned int base, unsigned int x)
{

    if (n > (base - 1) || 32 - x > 0) {
        base_aux(n / base, base, ++x);
        printf("%u", n % base);
    }
    else {
        printf("%u", n);
    }

}

void binary_int(unsigned int n)
{
    base_aux(n, 2, 0);
}

int main()
{
    binary_int(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using an array of precalculated size (maximal number of digits required), pre-initialised to '0':

```
static char const characters[36] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

void base_aux2(unsigned int n, unsigned int base, char* end)
{
    if(n != 0)
    {
        *--end = characters[n % base];
        base_aux2(n / base, base, end);
    }
}

void base_aux(unsigned int n, unsigned int base)
{
    if(base > sizeof(characters))
    {
        printf("base %u exceeding max of %lu", base, (unsigned long) sizeof(characters));
        return;
    }

    unsigned int digits = 0;
    unsigned int tmp = UINT_MAX;
    while(tmp)
    {
        tmp /= base;
        ++digits;
    }

    char buffer[digits];
    memset(buffer, '0', sizeof(buffer));

#if 0
    char* end = buffer + sizeof(buffer);
    while(n > 0)
    {
        *--end = characters[n % base];
        n /= base;
    }
#else
    base_aux2(n, base, buffer + sizeof(buffer));
#endif

    printf("%.*s\n", (int)sizeof(buffer), buffer);
}
```

You are forced to use recursion? Fine, you get it with base_aux2...